# Generator for an infinite recursive series

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator

Here's the formula I want to implement:

Given `x`, `y`, we define `x+x^y` and continue: `... + (x**x**y)`

That is: the next term is the exponent of the 2 anterior terms piling up.

So we get:

```
x + [x**y] + [x**(x**y)] + [x**y]**[x**(x**y)] + ...
```

Comment: I'm getting confuse here, could you be elaborating it bit further ?

Comment: it's something like fibonnaci generator. In fibonnaci you get the first 2 of the series and then third is the sum etc
this is similar but the formula is the third is first exponential second and so on (all previous goes to exponent)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an infinite series, as you note, we'll implement it as a generator so we can pull off terms of the series:

```
def series_generator(x, y):

    y = (x**y)

    while True:
        yield x

        x, y = y, (x**y)

generator = series_generator(2, 3)

print(sum(next(generator) for _ in range(3)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
266
```

However, the terms of this series grow very fast and very quickly take a long time to compute.  The next series term to be added in this example is:

1552518092300708935148979488462502555256886017116696611139052038026050952686376886330878408828646477950487730697131073206171580044114814391444287275041181139204454976020849905550265285631598444825262999193716468750892846853816057856

And computing the next will take so long as to never return.  To convince myself that this was doing as you describe, I made a symbolic version:

```
def series_generator(x='x', y='y'):

    y = f"({x}**{y})"

    while True:
        yield str(x)

        x, y = y, f"({x}**{y})"

generator = series_generator(2, 3)

print(" + ".join(next(generator) for _ in range(4)))
```

Whose output is:

```
2 + (2**3) + (2**(2**3)) + ((2**3)**(2**(2**3)))
```

Or, if you leave off the arguments to `series_generator()`:

```
x + (x**y) + (x**(x**y)) + ((x**y)**(x**(x**y)))
```